# How can I transfer text messages from Nokia Lumia 930 to my PC?

Tags: sms

Would like to retain their integrity and strings,and read on my laptop as I do on phone, Could do this years ago with old small Nokia phone but struggling with this one

Comment: Try searching before asking a question, most common questions have already been answered.

Comment: thanks. I did search before my initial post but only found comments indicating this was not possible. I was hoping someone may now have a solution. It cannot be that difficult

Comment: OK thanks, I now found some other suggestions and will try those